# Handling an empty array with the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input."

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise

I have a react / redux / node express app that manages patient information.  I have a bug with reading new data after I've deleted a patient encounter.  The functions work fine until I delete the last encounter associated with the patient.  Then there's an error:  "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input."

To get around having no data passed along, I've tried to check if a 204 status comes back (no content) and I create an empty array and send that along as my JSON response instead of no data.  This hasn't fixed the error.

How can I handle the lack of content without an error being raised in the console?  Instead of returning [ ] (empty array) I've also tried returning ' [ ] ' (empty array with single quotes around it) (which I thought was valid JSON), but no luck.

```
readPatientEncounters(id) {
    let url = '/encounters/findPatient/'+id;
    Data.readData(url,(response) => {
        if (response.length !== 0) {
            response.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.date-b.date;
            });
        }
        this.props.dispatch(EncountersActions.readEncounters(response));
    }, (errorMessage) => {
        console.log('having an error>',errorMessage);
    });
}

class Data {
    static readData(path, onSuccess, onFailure) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-access-token': sessionStorage.getItem('jwt') });
        let myInit = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'headers': headers
        };
        let url = config.server_url + path;
        fetch(url, myInit).then(response => {
            var jsonResponse = response.json();
            if (response.status === 204) {
                return [];
            } else {
                return jsonResponse;
            }
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
            onSuccess(jsonResponse);
            return;
        }).catch(errorMessage => {
            onFailure(errorMessage);
            return errorMessage;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What output do you get when you console log response.status and jsonResponse?

Comment: response.status === 204 is working as intended. It's returning an empty array.  jsonResponse also looks like I expect it will.  It has content when reading data and the empty array when not reading data.  IT runs the onSuccess code, and appears to be getting the error when it does the return in the 2nd .then

Comment: is onSuccess a function that you've defined yourself? If so, where/ what does it do?

Comment: from my console log:  /encounters/findPatient/5900eb2d4a0d410d4724db42 after on success= []

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Yes but I mean, what does the onSuccess code do?

Comment: I am passing 2 functions into Data.readData, onSuccess and onFailure.  You can see that function is expecting those functions when it's called.

Read patient encounters is sending this function for the onSuccess:

    (response) => {
        if (response.length !== 0) {
            response.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.date-b.date;
            });
        }
        this.props.dispatch(EncountersActions.readEncounters(response));
    }

Comment: The onSuccess code sorts it alphabetically if there's  content there and it updates the store with the new data that was read.  I tried commenting out all that code and the error persists.

Comment: Okay, and if you comment out the code inside of that if-statement and just console log response, what do you get?

Comment: I tried commenting out all that code and the error persists.

Comment: you're running `var jsonResponse = response.json();` regardless of validity of response

Comment: That solved it.  Thanks Jaromanda X.  I filled in the solution and gave you credit.

Comment: No problem @MikeRisher - reading the comments I was unsure if you had already tried that or not :p

Answer (score 2):

The solution was provided by jaromanda-x 
 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x)

This code was converting to JSON format regardless of the response:

```
 var jsonResponse = response.json();
    if (response.status === 204) {
        return [];
    } else {
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

This solved this issue:

```
if (response.status === 204) {
    return [];
} else {
    return response.json();
}
```